# WCF using basicHttpBinding /customBinding on .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, binding

I try to connect to another WCF server use proxy which using basicHttpBinding /customBinding for binding on my .net 4.0 but it doen't work :[Server Error in '/' Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps4jv.png)
my web.config file :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ServicesSoap">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ServicesSoap1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ServicesSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://Test.com/LineTest/services.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoap"
                contract="Test.ServicesSoap" name="ServicesSoap" />
            <endpoint address="https://Test.com//LineTest/services.asmx"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoap12"
                contract="Test.ServicesSoap" name="ServicesSoap12" />
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetBinding="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restBehavior">
              <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
      <services>
        <service name="WCFServerForMobile.WCFServerForAlineTest">
          <endpoint name="ServerForAlineTest" contract="WCFServerForMobile.WCFServerForAlineTest" binding="wsHttpBinding" address="AlineTest" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"></endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

`

Is there any way to solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

[httpGetBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not accept boolean but `Binding`. You should put your binding name instead.

Instead of:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetBinding="true"/>
```

Use:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpGetBinding="basicHttpBinding"/>
```